# Why would multiple activation layers be used in a row?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning-model, activation-function

I'm learning about ML and I was looking at

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

model = InceptionV3(input_shape=(150, 150, 3), include_top=False, weights=None)
model.summary()
```

and I would for instance see

> activation_78 (Activation)  (None, 3, 3, 384)            0         ['batch_normalization_78[0][0]
> ']
> activation_79 (Activation)  (None, 3, 3, 384)            0         ['batch_normalization_79[0][0]
> ']

in the output. Generally speaking I see multiple occurrences of having 2 Activation layers that are not interlaced with any other layer.

Given that relu(x) = 0 if x < 0 or x, then relu(relu(x)) = relu(x). So I'm not sure to understand what is the point of these "duplicate" activation layers. Anyone can explain?

Note: I checked `model.get_layer("activation_<i>").activation` for all activation layers and they are ALL `function relu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of InceptionV3, these activations have different inputs and different outputs. It's not obvious when looking at a model.summary(), but becomes apparent when graphing with `from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model`

[image]